# Django File-Directory inside Python

Tags: python, django, csv, filereader

I have created a CSV-FileReader inside a Django-Project.
My question is where to put the csv-file ?

My code looks so:

```
with open(self.csvfile) as csvfile:
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
# Skip first line from csv-file
csvreader.next()
for row in self.read_csv(csvreader):
    # ....
```

Where is the best place inside a django-project to put my csvfile "self.csvfile" and what is the best way to reference it.

I think it is not nice, that self.csvfile would be a rel-path like `/etc/blah/blah/blah/*.csv`

I hope somebody could give me a nice tip.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` for static files, Django has `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` to manage other files like those uploaded by users, for more details, check out the documentation of [Managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/files/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a static directory in your Django-Project and save all your files in that folder.

static/ 
 css/
  sytle.css
 js/
  myscript.js
 csv/
  file1.csv
  file2.csv